# Why would a websocket created with pywebsocket be closed automatically?

Tags: python, apache, websocket, mod-pywebsocket

I want to test websocket with [pywebsocket](http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/), after some configurations following some instructions I found on the Internet, I finally got it run.
Then I want to try the echo example: http://code.google.com/p/pywebsocket/source/browse/trunk/src/example/console.html
the websocket is connected successfully, and I can do those send and receive things, however, after about 10 seconds since the websocket was established, the websocket was closed automatically. Every time it works like this. I tested it with Chromium 11 on Ubuntu 11.04 with apache. Any ideas?

Comment: Instead of editing the question title, just post the solution as an answer and then accept it. It is perfectly fine to answer your own question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the solution by myself, modify `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/reqtimeout.conf` to change the timeout time to 60 seconds.