# pywebsocket doesnt work

Tags: apache, websocket, mod-pywebsocket

This is how I've installed `mod_pywebsocket` as apache extension

```
root@senior:/var/www# wget http://pywebsocket.googlecode.com/files/mod_pywebsocket-0.7.8.tar.gz
root@senior:/var/www# tar xvf mod_pywebsocket-0.7.8.tar.gz
root@senior:/var/www# cd pywebsocket-0.7.8/src/
root@senior:/var/www/pywebsocket-0.7.8/src# py:/./setpuup.py build
running build
running build_py
root@senior:/var/www/pywebsocket-0.7.8/src# python ./setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
running install_lib
running install_egg_info
Removing /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_pywebsocket-0.7.8.egg-info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_pywebsocket-0.7.8.egg-info    
root@senior:/var/www/pywebsocket-0.7.8/src# mkdir /var/www/_wsh/
root@senior:/var/www/pywebsocket-0.7.8/src# cp example/* /var/www/_wsh/
root@senior:/var/www/pywebsocket-0.7.8/src# cd /var/www/_wsh/
root@senior:/var/www/_wsh# chmod a+x *.py
root@senior:/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_pywebsocket# cd /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_pywebsocket
root@senior:/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_pywebsocket# chmod a+rx *.py
```

Here is mine text inserted in **httpd.conf**

```
<IfModule python_module>
  PythonPath "sys.path+['/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages']"
  PythonOption mod_pywebsocket.handler_root /var/www/_wsh/
  PythonOption mod_pywebsocket.handler_scan /var/www/_wsh/
  #PythonOption mod_pywebsocket.allow_draft75 On
  #<Location /var/www/_vsh>
  #  PythonHeaderParserHandler mod_pywebsocket.headerparserhandler
  #</Location>
</IfModule>
```

After apaceh restart, I'm trying `console.html` code from examples of pywebsocket directory (copied in /var/www/_wsh). But it doesnt work, I cant open the connection.

When I try to run example I got this

```
root@senior:/usr# /var/www/_wsh/echo_client.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/_wsh/echo_client.py", line 995, in <module>
    main()
  File "/var/www/_wsh/echo_client.py", line 991, in main
    EchoClient(options).run()
  File "/var/www/_wsh/echo_client.py", line 840, in run
    self._handshake.handshake()
  File "/var/www/_wsh/echo_client.py", line 385, in handshake
    'Expected HTTP status code 101 but found %r' % status_code)
__main__.ClientHandshakeError: Expected HTTP status code 101 but found '200'
```

Could you please help me find out where is the problem? Thank you

Comment: Status code 200 means success, so it seems the code is expecting 101 instead of 200.

Comment: Try enabling `allow_draft75` line in the conf.

Comment: Also, try removing `PythonPath` line and add your mod_pywebsocket path directly to path, or create environment variable PYTHON_PATH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading many tutorials on how to set up `pywebsockets`, I've ended up with this configuration:

```
LogLevel debug
<IfModule python_module>
  Timeout 0
  #This is path where I have copied pywebsocket
  PythonPath "sys.path+['/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages']"
  #This is path where I have my websocket connection handlers (files that responds to requests, I have there example files copied too)
  PythonOption mod_pywebsocket.handler_root /var/www/websockets/
  PythonOption mod_pywebsocket.handler_scan /var/www/websockets/
  PythonHeaderParserHandler mod_pywebsocket.headerparserhandler
</IfModule>
```

Here is list of this paths for better understanding of where is what:

```
root@senior:/var/www/websockets# ls /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/
mod_pywebsocket  mod_pywebsocket-0.7.8.egg-info
root@senior:/var/www/websockets# ls /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_pywebsocket
common.py       handshake                __init__.pyc        mux.pyc             _stream_hixie75.pyc  util.pyc
common.pyc      headerparserhandler.py   memorizingfile.py   standalone.py       _stream_hybi.py
dispatch.py     headerparserhandler.pyc  memorizingfile.pyc  standalone.pyc      _stream_hybi.pyc
dispatch.pyc    http_header_util.py      msgutil.py          _stream_base.py     stream.py
extensions.py   http_header_util.pyc     msgutil.pyc         _stream_base.pyc    stream.pyc
extensions.pyc  __init__.py              mux.py              _stream_hixie75.py  util.py
root@senior:/var/www/websockets#
root@senior:/var/www/websockets# ls .
bench_wsh.py  console.html    echo_wsh.py      origin_check_wsh.py
close_wsh.py  echo_client.py  handler_map.txt  pywebsocket.conf
```

I also had to edit [mod_reqtimeout](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_reqtimeout.html) of apache to keep connection alive (see this question for more info [Why would a websocket created with pywebsocket be closed automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6030436/why-would-a-websocket-created-with-pywebsocket-be-closed-automatically) )

Answer (score 1):

It is much easier to run it as standalone server. Have you tried that?

```
"""Standalone WebSocket server.

Use this file to launch pywebsocket without Apache HTTP Server.


BASIC USAGE

Go to the src directory and run

  $ python mod_pywebsocket/standalone.py [-p <ws_port>]
                                         [-w <websock_handlers>]
                                         [-d <document_root>]

<ws_port> is the port number to use for ws:// connection.

<document_root> is the path to the root directory of HTML files.

<websock_handlers> is the path to the root directory of WebSocket handlers.
If not specified, <document_root> will be used. See __init__.py (or
run $ pydoc mod_pywebsocket) for how to write WebSocket handlers.

For more detail and other options, run

  $ python mod_pywebsocket/standalone.py --help

or see _build_option_parser method below.

For trouble shooting, adding "--log_level debug" might help you.
```

**Update**

Try [this link](http://code.google.com/p/websocket-sample/wiki/HowToInstallMod_pywebsocket) for fixing your issue.

Comment: Yes I've tried, but I cant open another port so I want to run websockets as apache plugin

Comment: I guess thats the link I have started all the configuration with (even before posting a question). When I compare my former config with actual, they differ only in `PythonHeaderParserHandler mod_pywebsocket.headerparserhandler`. I've just had it wrongly set. Standalone version runs without any problem, but as I've written, I didnt want to use another port